# Random number generator and validator

Tags: python

This is my code for a gtin-8 number generator

```
barcode = []
inputChoice = 0
inputChoice = 1
checkNumber = 0
placeHolder = 0

def generate():
    generate = 0
    for i in str(Userinput):
        barcode.append(int(i))
    print(barcode)
    for i in range (0,6,2):
        generate += barcode[i] *3
        print('Generate is now ',generate)
    print(generate)

def checkNumber():
    for i in str(Userinput):
        checkNumber += int(i)
        placeHolder += int(i)
    checkNumber = round(checkNumber, -1)
    checkNumber = (checkNumber - placeHolder) % 10
    return(checkNumber)

def check():
    jk = 0

def main():
    inputChoice=0
    while inputChoice !=9 and inputChoice !=1 and inputChoice!=2:
        inputChoice=int(input("chose 1 to get GTIN,2 to check,9 to exit\n"))
        Userinput = (input("input the barcode \n"))
    if inputChoice==1 :
        if len(Userinput) !=7:
            print("make sure you inputted 7 inegers")
    if inputChoice == 2:
        if len(Userinput) !=8:
            print("Make sure you input 8 integers")
    else:
            generate(Userinput)
    return(Userinput)

Userinput = main()
generate()
checkNumber()
```

I have made a function called check number, generate and main but when I run a code it gives me this error:

> TypeError: generate() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

I am unsure why this is the case, jk = 0 is there as I have not finished that function and I am just using it as a placeholder.

Comment: In the `else` block of your `main` function, you're calling `generate` with `Userinput` as an argument. Your function is declared as taking no arguments.

Comment: I didn't check every thing but at least you called `generate(Userinput)` in the last `else` of your `main()` function.

Comment: So what would i need to do to correct this

Answer (score 1):

works fine after adding *args, than we get

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'checkNumber' referenced before assignment
```

so add default args in the flag of checkNumber()

```
def generate(*args): #<<<< edit
    generate = 0
    for i in str(Userinput):
        barcode.append(int(i))
    print(barcode)
    for i in range (0,6,2):
        generate += barcode[i] *3
        print('Generate is now ',generate)
    print(generate)

def checkNumber(checkNumber=0, placeHolder=0): #<<<< edit
    for i in str(Userinput):
        checkNumber += int(i)
        placeHolder += int(i)
    checkNumber = round(checkNumber, -1)
    checkNumber = (checkNumber - placeHolder) % 10
    return(checkNumber)
```

that its works finaly result with 1515155155151 as barcode:

```
chose 1 to get GTIN,2 to check,9 to exit
 2
input the barcode 
 1515155155151
Make sure you input 8 integers
[1, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 5, 1]
Generate is now  3
Generate is now  6
Generate is now  9
9
```

Comment: Stupid question but what are args nevermind i just googled it and its arguments

Comment: @aadoma123 "Arguments" aka the inputs for your function

Comment: @aadoma123 i think you should take a look at http://www.learnpython.org/en/Multiple_Function_Arguments

Answer (score 0):

Ok you asked for feedback so here we go...

Point #1: dont use globals when you dont need them. Hint : you can write huge (10+klocs) programs without a single global (talking about globals that are modified or reassigned during execution of course - pseudo-constants etc are ok). Practicaly, this starts by writing pure functions - functions that take arguments, return results, and for which the same set of arguments will always produce the same results

Point #2: respect the language's usual coding conventions (cf [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for Python)

Point #3: learn the language's idioms - in your example,

- use of `str.format()`
- use of list comprehensions or generator expressions instead of `for` loops where it makes sense,
- a `main()` function that is **really** a `main` function and is guarded by a `if __name__ == "__main__":` check)

Here's an example of what your code could look like once those points are fixed:

```
def generate(source):
    barcode = [int(c) for c in source]
    result = sum(barcode[i] * 3 for i in range(0, 6, 2))
    return result, barcode

def check_number(source):
    placeholder = checksum = sum(int(i) for i in source)
    checksum = round(checksum, -1)
    checksum = (checksum - placeholder) % 10
    return checksum

def check(what):
    jk = 0


def main():
    choice = 0
    while True:
        choice = input("chose 1 to get GTIN, 2 to check, 9 to exit\n").strip()
        try:
            choice = int(choice)
            if choice not in (1, 2, 9):
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid value '{}'".format(choice))
            continue

        if choice == 9:
            return

        while True:
            source = input("input the barcode \n").strip()
            # source should contain only digits
            try:
                int(source)
            except ValueError:
                print("Make sure you entered only integers")
                continue

            if choice == 1 and  len(source) != 7:
                print("Make sure you entered 7 integers")
                continue
            elif choice == 2 and len(source) != 8:
                print("Make sure you entered 8 integers")
                continue
            else:
                # ok, valid input
                break

        if choice == 1:
            result, barcode = generate(source)
            print("barcode : {}.".format(barcode))
            print("result : {}".format(result))

        elif choice == 2:
            raise NotImplementedError("check is not yet implemented")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you help , now when i run the code this error shows up , File "C:/Users/.../Desktop/sure.py", line 59, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/.../Desktop/sure.py", line 19, in main
    choice = input("chose 1 to get GTIN, 2 to check, 9 to exit\n").strip()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: by the way im using python 2.7.12 if that helps